# I need multiple buttons to conduct the same function - to concatenate a URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, weather

I am currently writing a code for my website that will display weather model data based on user selected options. Each selection builds a URL that will link to an image from NOAA - the model data.

My algorithm is basically this, a user selects a weather model, NAM, HRRR or GFS - then a sector is selected, CONUS, Northeast, USA etc - finally, a simulated parameter is selected such as Simulated Radar, Cloud Cover etc. (each of these is captured by the value of a button push and is assigned to a variable that concatenates a URL using js).

The problem is, my JavaScript can only gather one value from one button, so I would have to copy/paste the code for each button. I would like this code to be reusable for each button. I am not very well rounded in js so any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Here is the very simple code I have so far for this:

```js
function sectorFuct() {
  var sector = document.getElementById("sectorbutton").value;
  console.log(sector);
}

function modelFuct() {
  var model = document.getElementById("modelButton").value;
  console.log(model);
}

function paramFuct() {
  var param = document.getElementById("parambutton").value;
  console.log(param);
  var sector = document.getElementById("sectorbutton").value;
  var model = document.getElementById("modelButton").value;
  var fullURL = ('https://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/data/' + model + '/12/' + model + '_' + sector + '_006_' + param + '.gif');
  console.log(fullURL);
}

function getData() {
  var param = document.getElementById("parambutton").value;
  var sector = document.getElementById("sectorbutton").value;
  var model = document.getElementById("modelButton").value;
  var fullURL = ('https://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/data/' + model + '/12/' + model + '_' + sector + '_006_' + param + '.gif');
  var src = fullURL;
  show_image(fullURL, 500, 400, "Model Data");
}

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<!--- select nam -> conus ->  850mb-700mb Thickness and img to view data --->
<button type="submit" ; value="nam" ; onClick="modelFuct()" ; id="modelButton" ; style="vertical-align:middle;"> nam </button><br>
<button type="submit" ; value="hrrr" ; onClick="modelFuct()" ; id="modelButton" ; style="vertical-align:middle;"> hrrr </button><br>
<button type="submit" ; value="gfs" ; onClick="modelFuct()" ; id="modelButton" ; style="vertical-align:middle;"> gfs </button><br>


<button type="submit" ; value="conus" ; onClick="sectorFuct()" ; id="sectorbutton" ; style="vertical-align:middle;"> Northeast US </button><br>
<button type="submit" ; value="850_700_thick" ; onClick="paramFuct()" ; id="parambutton" ; style="vertical-align:middle;"> 850mb-700mb Thickness </button><br>
<button onclick="getData();">img</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using submit buttons instead of menus or radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. `document.getElementById()` doesn't care which button you clicked on, it will always return the first element with that ID.

The functions should take parameters, which tell them which button was clicked. You can then pass `this` as the argument to mean the clicked button.

Then you can save the values of the clicked buttons in global variables, which are used by the `getData()` function.

Also, you don't need to separate attributes in an HTML element with `;`.

```js
var sector;
var model;
var param;

function sectorFuct(button) {
  sector = button.value;
  console.log(sector);
}

function modelFuct(button) {
  model = button.value;
  console.log(model);
}

function paramFuct(button) {
  param =  button.value;
  console.log(param);
}

function getData() {
  if (!param || !sector || !model) {
    alert("Select a sector, model, and parameter first");
    return;
  }
  var fullURL = ('https://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/data/' + model + '/12/' + model + '_' + sector + '_006_' + param + '.gif');
  var src = fullURL;
  show_image(fullURL, 500, 400, "Model Data");
}

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<!--- select nam -> conus ->  850mb-700mb Thickness and img to view data --->
<button type="submit" value="nam" onClick="modelFuct(this)" style="vertical-align:middle;"> nam </button><br>
<button type="submit" value="hrrr" onClick="modelFuct(this)" style="vertical-align:middle;"> hrrr </button><br>
<button type="submit" value="gfs" onClick="modelFuct(this)" style="vertical-align:middle;"> gfs </button><br>


<button type="submit" value="conus" onClick="sectorFuct(this)" style="vertical-align:middle;"> Northeast US </button><br>
<button type="submit" value="850_700_thick" onClick="paramFuct(this)" style="vertical-align:middle;"> 850mb-700mb Thickness </button><br>
<button onclick="getData();">img</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I have a very limited knowledge of JavaScript as you can probably guess. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose, you can try something like this:

1. **"document.querySelectorAll("button")** --> to grab all the "buttons" 
   1.1 This will create a **NodeList** (that you can iterate like an Array, but there some incompatibilities with some browsers)
   1.2 The "fix" for this incompatibilities, is setting this NodeList to an **Array**, using the **Array.protopype**.
   Having your NodeList with **let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")**, and converting it to an Array with, per example: **let buttonsArray= Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons)**
2. With all "buttons" in place, you can use per example **forEach() method**.
   Accessing each item in the callback function

3 - And finally in each button, adding an **Event Listener**, that will concatenate your URL whenever a button is clicked.

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
let url = ""

buttons.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        url = url + " " + item.value 
    })
})
```

Hope it's helpful.